# Convert dataframe into a payload using custom-made SOAP-Envelope?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

I have a Python project where I am supposed to convert my dataframe into a payload for POST API hit (on a SAP server). This payload must be in a particular format/SOAP Envelope which I received using the WSDL URL. **I need help in framing the SOAP Envelope using the dataframe that I have.**

Below is the code I am using to Post the data.

```
import requests

url = 'my SAP url'


# structured XML
payload = df_xml_test.to_xml()
certificate_file = "certificate.pem"

# headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'
}

# POST request
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload,
                            cert=certificate_file,verify=False)
  
# prints the response
print(response.text)
print(response)
```

I received a Response `500` instead of a Response `200`.

Comment: Please clarify the question. If the question is about the meaning of 500, you can find easily that it's an error in the code which is called, so nobody can help you on that, you need to get the logs from the SAP software you call or get the whole response which may contain more information.

Comment: Hello @Sandra Rossi

Apologies for the mistake in the question.
The question is not regarding the Response 500. I need help in framing the SAP - xml Envelope using the dataframe that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did using string append and iterations

Comment: Is this a question? A comment?

Comment: could you please post the full solution?